# Freezes when installing grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, filesystem

I tried to install Linux Mint or Ubuntu on a lenovo Q180, it freezes when installing grub2. Used a live usb stick to install it.

I was told to "rewrite the mbr" to fix the problem. Trying so I installed boot-repair, bit it only offers me sdb which is my usb stick, not the hard drive. I have no idea what's wrong, in gparted and in the setup process it appears normal.

All data including the windows recovery partition is already intentionally deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I switched to a windows installation stick, installed windows and used the commands:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

Installing windows was probably not necessary.